# How to display additional text to searchBar?

Tags: objective-c, uisearchbar

[image]

I don't know how i can display a Text on the right of the search bar. in this case i want to do the same. Pass the total number of results as is shown on the image. Any ideas?

Comment: you can place label behide the searchbar at that position and update it with total search result.

Comment: I tried, but when adding it does not let me add it ontop.

Comment: not on the top of search field, but below the searchbar , and dont forget to adjust the alpha value (0.85).

Comment: I get this.. http://imageshack.com/a/img839/2130/uua6.png

Comment: its a prompt value right ?

Comment: yes... it does not allow labels either ontop or below or near  to it.

Comment: check this , i have made this for you [snap link](https://www.dropbox.com/s/wjotpjep49t3f0m/Screen%20Shot%202014-05-25%20at%2012.58.22%20AM.png), the only difference is it a viewcontroller not tableview controller.

Comment: I'm using a Navegation Controller with a SearchBar instead of a SearchBar and display controller. How you did that?

Comment: I see what you mean @pawan I did a sample on a viewController. But sadly it does not work on what I'm using :(